# Battery status - bluetooth device windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, bluetooth, device

what library would you need in windows phone 8 to get status of battery (if it needs to charge) for a bluetooth device?

We can already get messages from the device, we just need info of the devices battery life.

Hope someone can guide us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how bluetooth works. Bluetooth is just a communication platform. That's it. It is just a common frequency that devices communicate on. The communications are completely proprietary.

For example, if you are trying to get the battery status from a smart watch it might be a code like 123 where as if you were trying to get it from a bluetooth toy it might be 321.

In order to figure out how to get the battery information back from your bluetooth device you need to find the developers documentation. If there is none then reach out to the company that made the device.

So in short, there is no standard way of pinging a device for battery information. It entirely depends on the protocol for that device.

Comment: There is a standard for that by the Bluetooth group. But it seems to depend on the Bluetooth LE standard because it uses the GATT profile.
Check out GATT UUID 0000180F-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb or the battery service protocol specs.
But of course someone would have to write a programme that displays the information still. And probably not many devices support this standard yet.